# Animate when certain pixels into viewport (Pen by Bramus)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following [pen by Bramus](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/yikfd) to animate(FadeInUp) divs when entering the viewport. However currently the div only starts fading in when the div is completely in the viewport. What I need is the flexibility to start the animation when a div is a certain pixels inside the viewport. For example it will start the animation FadeInUp when the div is 100 pixels in the viewport. How can I do this with the current code/pen I'm using (see code below)?

Is this also possible with percentages? F.e. when a div is 20% in viewport the animation starts?

Thanks.

```
jQuery(function($) {

// Function which adds the 'animated' class to any '.animatable' in view
var doAnimations = function() {

 // Calc current offset and get all animatables
var offset = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
  $animatables = $('.animatable');

// Check all animatables and animate them if necessary
$animatables.each(function(i) {
 var $animatable = $(this);
if (($animatable.offset().top + $animatable.height() - 20) < offset) {
$animatable.removeClass('animatable').addClass('animated');
        }
});

};

// Hook doAnimations on scroll, and trigger a scroll
$(window).on('scroll', doAnimations);
$(window).trigger('scroll');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Offsetting is already foreseen in the code. Tweak the value of `20` in this line:

`if (($animatable.offset().top + $animatable.height() - 20) < offset) {`

You might also need to change the `-` sign to a `+` to suit your needs.

Comment: I played around with the minus and plus and the number, it results for me in either: The div is faded in when it is 100% or more in the viewport or it is already faded in before I reach the div. I'm still learning the use of Javascript. What I want is when the div is 10px in the viewport the div will start to fade in. Can you explain to me what the individual elements in this code do, so I understand what is going on?

Another thing: for me this code doesn't work and give an error in Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.109): TypeError: $animatables.size is not a function
I use jQuery 3.2.1.

Comment: I managed to fix the error given on jQuery.com: "The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead."

Comment: Do note that the pen was created back in 2013 and uses jQuery 1.10 … to use it with jQuery 3.2.1 some adjustments will need to be made.

Comment: Yes I understand. So far the only error in 3.2.1 is the .size (adjusted to .length). Rest of the code seems to work just fine (no errors in Chrome).